# Python logging special characters to file throws exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, unicode, special-characters

I have a logger which logs to file but occasionally when it encounters TM characters it throws an exception and the entry is not logged.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/logs/log.log',
    level=logging.INFO, 
    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
```

What's wrong with it?

**Edit:**

Those are time and message obviously. The message is being received from google chrome via websocket as a stringified object {log: log} which is then parsed using data=json.loads(obj). Then data["log"] string goes into message.

Comment: What is a TM character?  What is in `asctime` and `message`?

Comment: Trademark character, it was saying that some characters could not be translated to unicode or something like that.

Comment: try putting `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` on the top of your script.

Comment: @najjarammar that won't help, the problem comes when the Unicode string is being encoded for writing to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of allowing `logger` to open the file, open it yourself and specify an encoding that can handle the character.

```
logfile = open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/logs/log.log', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
logging.basicConfig(stream=logfile,
    level=logging.INFO, 
    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
```

Comment: This one gives me another error - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: It's called inside a class btw, could this be the problem?

Comment: @Anonymous Once the `with` block exits the file is closed.  Do all your logging within the block, or use a simple `logfile = open(...)` and use `logfile.close()` when you are done with it.

Comment: In order for this to work I would need to put my entire script under inside the with block.

Comment: logfile = open(...) worked instead of with. I will be testing to see if the above answer solves my entire problem